# How to add Python Kivy Touch Ripple at a specific Coordinate/Widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I was working with buttons and wanted to add touch ripple effect. I'm able to make the ripple effect all over the screen but not at a pre-specified coordinate or limited to widgets only. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance, it really means a lot.
Note- backg.png is just a plain blue background image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import RoundedRectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior

Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            Image:
                size_hint: 1, 1
                source: "backg.png"
                pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.0}
                keep_ratio: False
                allow_stretch: True
            Widget:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 255, 1
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: 230, 50
                        segments: 10
                        radius: [(10.0, 10.0), (10.0, 10.0), (10.0, 10.0), (10.0, 10.0)]
                        pos: 20, 500
            Widget:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 0, 255, 1
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: 50, 50
                        segments: 10
                        radius: [(25.0, 25.0), (25.0, 25.0), (25.0, 25.0), (25.0, 25.0)]
                        pos: 20, 100
            RipFunction:
            Button:
                text: ''
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
                pos_hint: {'x':.4, 'y':.5}
                background_color: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5
                on_press:
""")

Window.size = (270, 570)


class RipFunction(TouchRippleBehavior, Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # print(touch)
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        # collide_point = self.collide_point(touch[0], touch[1])
        if collide_point:
            touch.grab(self)
            self.ripple_duration_in = 0.7
            self.ripple_scale = 0.1
            self.ripple_show(touch)
            return True
        return False

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self.ripple_duration_out = 0.4
            self.ripple_fade()
            return True
        return False

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly, and the ripple effect is limited to your `RipFunction` `Widget`. The problem is that you haven't set the size or position of the `RipFunction`, so it use the default position of `(0,0)` and the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`. So the `RipFunction` fills the entire display. Try modifying your `kv`:

```
        RipFunction:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 50, 50
            pos: 20, 150
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Comment: Thanks John, I was troubled by this thing for 2 days. I've got it now. Cheers.